# Handling button click inside a repeater using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, repeater, custom-data-attribute

I have a repeater with a button inside its item template. I have added some data attributes to the button and want to have access to them when a button is clicked using jQuery.

I tried following methods but either the function does not get hit when button is clicked or I get 'undefined'.

First try, I added an onclick event to the button:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpt_PrintCert" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li role="presentation"> 
            <button type="button" 
                id="btnPrintCert" 
                class="btn btn-sm certPrint" 
                aria-hidden="true" 
                aria-label="Submit"
                data-CatID ='<%# Eval("CourseCategoryID")%>'
                data-CourseLevel='<%# Eval("CourseLevel")%>'
                data-CourseCategory='<%# Eval("CourseCategory")%>'
                onclick='printCertificate();>Print Certificate</button>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

function printCertificate() {
    var catID = $(this).data('CatID')
    var courseCategory = $('#btnPrintCert').data('CourseCategory')
    __doPostBack('btnPDF', JSON.stringify({ type: "PDF", action: "Print", CategoryID: catID, ... }));
}
```

this shows catID and courseCategory as 'undefined'. Makes sense since controls inside repeater have different IDs.

Next, I tried using button's class:

```
$('.certPrint').click(function () {debugger
    var catID = $('.certPrint').data('CatID');
});
```

Also tried: $('.certPrint').attr('data-CatID');

this function doesn't even get hit when button is clicked.

Anything else I can try?

Comment: With the onclick way, try using `this` instead of `$('.certPrint')`

Comment: In your printCertificate() method, shouldn't it be `$('.certPrint').data('CourseCategory')` instead of `$('btnPrintCert').data('CourseCategory')`.

Answer (score 0):

You've a typo in :

```
$('.cerPrint').data('CatID');
```

Should be :

```
$('.certPrint').data('CatID');
_______^
```

Or simply use `this` :

```
$(this).data('CatID');
```

For :

```
var courseCategory = $('btnPrintCert').data('CourseCategory')
```

You should use id selctor `#` or use this instead like :

```
var courseCategory = $('#btnPrintCert').data('CourseCategory');
________________________^
//Or
var courseCategory = $(this).data('CourseCategory');
```

Comment: I fixed the typos. Issue still exists whether I use onclick function, which does get hit but returns 'undefined', or if I remove it and try to use $('.certPrint').click() which doesn't even get hit when button is clicked. I also fixed the missing hashtag.

Comment: When I put a breakpoint in onclick() function, $this has length 1 and $this[0] has no 'attribute' or 'data' property and has length 0.

Comment: Do you mean `$(this)` ?

Comment: Try to attach the event using event delegation instead like `$('body').on('click', '.certPrint', function () {`. avoid the use of `id=".."` attribute inside repeater since it will generate duplicate ids what lead your HTML to invalid format.

Comment: I changed it to what you suggested, it does get hit when button is clicked but still "catID" is 'undefined'. $('body').on('click', '.certPrint', function () { var catID = $(this).data('CatID'); }); I believ use of $(this) here is incorrect since it is referring to body (is it?).

Comment: still stuck on this. Any ideas to resolve is appreciated.

Comment: UPDATE - I can access data-CatID attribute if I use $(this)[0].attributes['data-CatID'].value. Similarly, if I use $('.CertPrint').click() event I can access data-CatID using $('#btnPrintCert')[0].attributes['data-CatID'].value. But is this correct way of accessing this?

Comment: Your suggestion works if you can confirm the way I am using it is correct; that is, if using $(this)[0].attributes['data-CatID'].value is correct. I get correct Category ID values for each button.

Comment: Hi man, Are you sure `$(this).data('CatID')` not work? since it should, try also `$(this).prop('data-CatID')` or `$(this).attr('data-CatID')`